# How do I disable landscape orientation in iPhone but keep it enabled on iPad?

Tags: ios, interface-orientation

I am looking to allow app rotation on an iPad, but would like to keep it disabled on the iPhone, as it is too narrow.

So far, I only see instructions on one device or the other, but not both.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Xcode 6 you have to edit `Info.plist`:

> [image]